# Trying to render Rmarkdown with a table using {r results='asis'} knitr::kable(Education)

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am new to RMarkdown!
I am trying to render a table with

```
{r results='asis'}
knitr::kable(tablex)
```

I had added the following chunks before the code chunk:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
require("knitr")
tablex<-read.csv("/tablex.csv",header=TRUE)
```

When I knit the .Rmd as PDF I get this error:

I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log svm-rmarkdown-cv.log.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> @{} >{\raggedleft \arraybackslash 
                                             }p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep ...
l.178 ...mnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.95}}@{}}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile svm-rmarkdown-cv.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See svm-rmarkdown-cv.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I had followed all the instructions on https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging and had updated all the Latex Package!
Any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: Don't use `results='asis'`.

Answer (score 1):

Are use your latex is is install properly, might be worth reinstalling

```
install.packages("tinytex")
library(tinytext)
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I ran into other issues right now with formatting kableExtra tables but trying figure out what the problem is.

Comment: If my answer guided you to a resolution, please consider giving it an upvote! Good luck on kableExtra